# Safest way to convert interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I have:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos: Position) => {
    this.navigation = pos.coords;
}
```

And:

```
interface INavigation {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
    <additional parameters>
}
```

But `position.coords` looks like this:

```
{
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    <additional parameters>
}
```

While its not codebreaking, I haven't seen much detail about how to handle this. I personally like the `lat` and `lng` shorthands, but I would obviously be willing to ditch them if it requires something extensive like an entire extra function.

So, what is the best way to take care of this? Should I abandon it and just go with the full name or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: And an adapter function `inavigate_to_coord` that handles the conversion  would be appropriate. I don't see that as "extensive".

Comment: Thanks, that what I wanted to know. Could you possibly provide an example? @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos: Position) => {
    const { longitude, latitude, ...props } = pos.coords;
    this.navigation = { lng: longitude, lat: latitude, ...props };
}
```

It's preferable to pick data structure that is closer to input data (API responses, etc), as long as this doesn't cause any other problems. This could be justified in the opposite case, because `lng` and `lat` are less readable. In this case I would personally go with `longitude` and `latitude` because this allows to skip additional transforms.